# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder no Contacts Evaluating

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I'm trying to create a new Shared Entry Event for my Interactions in Marketing Cloud Journey Builder and the Entry Event continues to show "0".

1. created a new Sendable Data Extension that contains EmailAddress and SubscriberKey attributes. EmailAddress is the primary key.
2. linked my DE to Contacts Builder, from ContactKey <=> EmailAddress.
3. In Contacts Configuration, added DE and its EmailAddress attribute to the Email Address channel order.
4. Journey Builder, created DE as the Entry Source, NO filters (so all new records should enter).
5. After activating the Journey and running the automation, the running journey shows "0 contacts evaluated for entry.

I'm not sure why the contactS are not being evaluated.

Comment: Did you use an Email Studio/Automation Studio Audience as the entry source or did you use an Event as the source?

Comment: If you are using Contact Data Event, your contact should be a part of a population or All Subscribers. If using Audience, it should work

Comment: I used Audience Builder > Contact Builder > Create Attribute Group to link the DE to Data Designer as an attribute group. The DE contains under 200 contacts. Would I still need to create a population instead?

Answer (score 3):

This typically occurs when you don't have a Population. You will need to create a Population in Contact Builder, where the Population is a Sendable Data Extension containing all your Contacts that may enter a Journey.

Answer (score 0):

Did you raised a case with marketing cloud support? Sometimes there are issues with the configuration on the backend and only support can fix it.